# How to remove "and" from author name?

Tags: authblk

This is my code:

```
\usepackage{authblk}
\title{ \vspace{-15mm}
\author[1]{Anand Shankar Singh}
\author[2]{Sukanta K Dash}
\author[3*]{Mahendra R Vanteru}
```

Output comes as:

> Anand Shankar Singh, Sukanta K Dash, and Mahendra R Vanteru.

I want to remove the `and`. How should I remove it?

Comment: See it [http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/preprint/authblk.pdf](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/preprint/authblk.pdf) on page 4.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se. Please don't post code fragments. Instead, edit your question to include the fragment into a compilable document that people can play with.

Comment: @Anandshankar did the answer suit your requirement -- if so please accept and /or upvote the answer

Comment: @AnandShankar  please accept the answer if it met the requirement

Answer (score 2):

Please see page 4 of the documentation available at -- http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/preprint/authblk.pdf

[image]

**With particular reference to `authand`**

[image]

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[left=3.00cm, right=3.00cm, top=2.00cm, bottom=2.00cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{authblk}

\renewcommand*{\Authsep}{, }
\renewcommand*{\Authand}{, }%<---------------remove and
\renewcommand*{\Authands}{, }
\renewcommand*{\Affilfont}{\normalsize}
%\renewcommand*{\Authfont}{\bfseries}    % make author names boldface    
\setlength{\affilsep}{2em}   % set the space between author and affiliation

\title{Aa Article Title}
\author[1]{Anand Shankar Singh}
\author[2]{Sukanta K Dash}
\author[3*]{Mahendra R Vanteru}
\affil[1]{Department of Chemical Engineering, University of AAAAA BBBBBB, CCCCC road, 
 XXXXX 200021, Y Country} 
\affil[2]{AAAAAA Laboratory, University of AAAAA BBBBBB, XXXXX 303939, Z Country}
\date{}    

\begin{document}
\maketitle

This is an article.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help

Comment: Thank you so much for your help

Answer (score 1):

To remove the ", and" before the last author, include:

```
\renewcommand*{\Authands}{, }
```

The minimum working example looks as follows:

```
\documentclass{article} % twoside for mirrored margins

\usepackage{authblk} % author + affiliation

\title{Title}

\author[1]{Author1}
\author[1]{Author2}
\author[2]{Author3}
\affil[1]{Afil1}
\affil[2]{Afil2}

\renewcommand*{\Authands}{, }

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

PS: I am very thankfull of @js bibra's answer which already includes this answer, as otherwise I wouldn't have solved the issue. But due to its verbosity and misleading "%<---------------remove and" comment I did not immediately understand it and misinterpreted it at first. This lead to me using up quite some time searching for alternative solutions.